# How to use `requests.Session` to rate limit requests to a given URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to ensure that consecutive requests to a URL are throttled with a given minimum latency between requests.

I've come across `requests.Session` hook events (https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks). Is there a way to configure these hook events (or another approach) to effectively throttle consecutive requests?

One restriction I have is that this behavior needs to be done as a modification/argument to a `requests.Session` object.

Answer (score 0):

A rough-around-the-edges approach using global state.

```py
def request_hook(r, *args, **kwargs):
    global last_request_time
    poll_latency = 0.5

    now = time.time()
    if now < poll_latency + last_request_time:
        time.sleep(min(poll_latency, poll_latency + last_request_time > now))
    last_request_time = time.time()

def get_session():
    global last_request_time

    last_request_time = time.time() - 100
    session = requests.Session()
    session.hooks['response'].append(request_hook)
    return session
```